# Error - Segmentation Fault

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run DQN, which is some AI for Atari.

Upon launching the program (`sudo bash run_cpu < the_name_of_the_game >`), I get the following error: `run_cpu: line 46:  9377 Segmentation fault      ../torch/bin/luajit train_agent.lua $args`

From [Running application ends with "Segmentation Fault"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132192/running-application-ends-with-segmentation-fault), the error seems to be coming from the program, but many other people have used it without any problem ...

How can I solve this?

I'm quite new to Linux, and I'm on Elementary OS (+-latest stable version)

I took the program here : https://sites.google.com/a/deepmind.com/dqn/

Comment: Which game are you training DQN on? Could you try without `sudo`?

Comment: @StephenKitt I have tried breakout and a 3D tic-tac-toe game. I have tried without sudo, it gives me the same error (just the number changes, it's still around 10000, that should be the process's ID (?))

Comment: Does the game program work on its own?

Comment: @HackSaw Do you mean the roms or the DQN ? I have tried several ROMs so they should be ok, and the DQN has been run successfully by other people.

Comment: I mean the game itself. If the game works outside of the learning framework, this suggests it's not the problem.

Comment: @HackSaw Both games do work (emulated on Stella)

Answer (score 1):

Is the ROM name capitalized? If so, make it lower case. For example:

```
    Breakout.bin ==> breakout.bin
```

Also make sure that you have 6GB of RAM!

Comment: Why do I need 6 GB or RAM ? (I only have 4)

Comment: Because the network is large and all the training happens in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are possibly misleading for a newbie. Let's say you have a game called "happy". The command line you type would be:

```
./run_cpu happy
```

That is, don't include the < or >.

In any case, you generally don't need to use sudo unless you get a permissions error.

Comment: I didn't include them, I just ran (for example) sudo bash run_cpu breakdown.

Comment: I use sudo because otherwise I get a 'Permission Denied' error. (sorry for being unclear in my question)

Comment: That's odd. At the top level of the Human_Level_Control_through_Deep_Reinforcement_Learning directory, try this command: "sudo chown -R $your_user_name ."  This will ensure everything in the directory is owned by you.

Comment: My concern is that something else has the wrong permissions, and a program is getting an error message instead of the expected output, which might cause a seg fault.

Comment: "sudo chown -R $hippa" gives me a 'chown: missing operand' error

Comment: The '.' at the end isn't punctuation. It's Unix-speak for "the current directory". Unix-speak for "the current directory's parent" is ".." If you run "ls -a" you'll see them.

Comment: So: sudo chown -R $hippa .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21657/discussion-between--and-hack-saw).